# using wsdl2java in ant target using CXF 3.0.9 jar

Tags: web-services, cxf, cxf-codegen-plugin

I am trying to build a project with cxf 3.0.9 jar. The current project is using cxf 2.7.11 and I need to upgrade it to cxf.3.0.9.But in cxf 3.0.9 there is no wsdl2java class available. In current build file I have a target with java **classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true" failonerror="true"**

This is not working with cxf 3.0.9 as there is no org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava in the jar. Can anyone please tell me how I can build the project with ant and wsdl2java using cxf 3.0.9.Attaching the ant build xml snippet for reference.

```html
<target name="wsdl2java">
      <java classname="org.apache.cxf.tools.wsdlto.WSDLToJava" fork="true" failonerror="true">
       <sysproperty key="exitOnFinish" value="true"/>
       <arg value="-all"/>
  <arg value="-fe"/>
  <arg value="jaxws21"/>  
        <arg value="-d"/>
        <arg value="src"/>
       <arg value="-b"/>
  <arg value="bindings.xml"/>   
       <arg value="-exsh"/>
       <arg value="true"/>
  <arg value="-dns"/> 
  <arg value="true"/>
  <arg value="-dex"/>
  <arg value="true"/>
  <arg value="-verbose"/>
  <arg value="-autoNameResolution"/>
        <arg value="${wsdl.url}"/>   
         <classpath>
            <path refid="cxf.deps"/>
         </classpath>
      </java>
   </target>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to add `cxf-tools-wsdlto-core-3.0.9-sources.jar` to your project. If you're using Maven the class will be automatically available. See [cxf-tools-wsdlto-core](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.cxf/cxf-tools-wsdlto-core/3.0.9)